Copy nodes including values into an existing xml using xpath
I have two xml created out of 2 dataverse tables, now I simply want to create a new xml that includes all those nodes (all cloned into one xml) that have the same value in a specific node, ie.
Dataverse 1 
    {
      "Array": {
                 "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
                 "cr46a_company_name": "123456",
                 "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
      },
   {
             "cr46a_internal_status": 6,
             "cr46a_company_name": "78901",
             "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
    },
    {
             "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
             "cr46a_company_name": "987654",
                 "cr46a_relation": "GHIJK"
    }   ,
 {
                     "cr46a_internal_status": 1,
                     "cr46a_company_name": "999999",
                     "cr46a_relation": "XXXXXX"
}

Dataverse 2
 {
          "Array": {
             "cr46a_partner_name": "Max Müller",
             "cr46a_end_date": "1.11.2024",
             "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF",
             "cr46a_email": "a@abc.de"
        
},
{
             "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Müller",
             "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024",
             "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
             "cr46a_email": "h@abc.de"
},
{
             "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Müller",
             "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024",
             "cr46a_relation": "GHIJK"
             "cr46a_email": "h@abc.de"
},
{   
             "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Max",
             "cr46a_end_date": "1.1.2025",
             "cr46a_relation": "WXYZ"
             "cr46a_email": "m@abc.de"
}

Now I want to create a merged set with all nodes that match the relation values into a new XML.
Record (combined where D1.relation = D2.relation):
       {
          "Array": {
      "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
     "cr46a_company_name": "123456",
     "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
     "cr46a_partner_name": "Max Müller",
     "cr46a_end_date": "01.11.2024",
     "cr46a_email": "a@abc.de"
},

{
         "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
         "cr46a_company_name": "123456",
         "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
         "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Müller",
         "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024",
         "cr46a_email": "h@abc.de"
},
{
         "cr46a_internal_status": 6,
         "cr46a_company_name": "78901",
         "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
         "cr46a_partner_name": "Max Müller",
         "cr46a_end_date": "1.11.2024",
         "cr46a_email": "a@abc.de"
},
{
         "cr46a_internal_status": 6,
         "cr46a_company_name": "78901",
         "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
         "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Müller",
         "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024",
         "cr46a_email": "h@abc.de"
},
{
         "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
         "cr46a_company_name": "987654",
         "cr46a_relation": "GHIJK"
         "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Müller",
         "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024",
         "cr46a_email": "h@abc.de"
}

Is that possible by any means without long iterations as the database is quite large with more than those nodes as examples?
This requires to iterate all items in a single xml and match and add to Array, which takes ages:
addProperty(variables('dataverse_1'), 'cr46a_partner_name', xpath(outputs('compose_dataverse_2'),concat('//Array[cr46a_relation/text()="',item()['cr46a_relation'],/cr46a_partner_name/text()'"]'))[0]) 

Finally, if the second dataverse array has no cr46a_relation the function breaks.
If possible I'd like to have a result set that looks like this:
{
  "cr46a_email": "h@abc.de", 
  "cr46a_partner_name": "Hans Müller",
  "elements": {
         "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
         "cr46a_company_name": "123456",
         "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
         "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024"},
{
         "cr46a_internal_status": 7,
         "cr46a_company_name": "987654",
         "cr46a_relation": "GHIJK"
         "cr46a_end_date": "30.10.2024"
}},
{
     "cr46a_email": "m@abc.de"
     "cr46a_partner_name": "Max Müller",
     "elements": {
         "cr46a_internal_status": 6,
         "cr46a_company_name": "78901",
         "cr46a_relation": "ABCDEF"
         "cr46a_end_date": "1.11.2024"},...
}

Do you have any solution?

XML or JSON?  Can you at least show us the exact format of the data you're working with?  It's really hard to help without it because the first thing we have to do is reconstruct/clean up your data to be in a proper format.

Hi, I don't mind if the solution is in JSON or XML or other means if  can transform the data in any way.

Sorry but can you provide some proper data and structures? It’s all a bit messy. My suggestion, take the actual data from dataverse and paste it in. Mask anything deemed sensitive.
